# Spring data best practice for preload data that considers application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-data, server-configuration

In my spring Data project there are some data that i prefer to fill with `data.sql`. They are some things like Image resources and Icons and logos.

My project have two `application.properties`. one for local developing and another for publishing on main server that have different `server.adress`
my problem is in `data.sql` can not import variable from properties:

```
INSERT INTO sticker_table( sticker_type, sticker_img_url , free_sticker) values (1,'http://192.168.34.24:8085/public/ic_avator_boy_1.png',true)
```

I can not consider `server.address` from selected properties in `data.sql`. I want **http://192.168.34.24:8085** for develop server and **http://192.168.24.250:8080** for publishing.

So how i can consider application.properties variable in data.sql or is there better way to fill data of server in start point?

Comment: How are executing the script?Can you not have a environment variable DEV/PROD set which can set using Spring @Value or something else and then depending on the variable load the properties file.Using the named variable in .sql file you can then replace the values from loaded properties just before executing the script.

Comment: @NitinPrabhu I execute like this: java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=propertyName application.jar   but could not get to how use properties variable in data.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the spring-data-jpa documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html), you can add a `data-${platform}.sql` to your spring boot project.  You could use that to separate out the difference between your local and remote server with `data-local.sql` and `data-remote.sql`.  Once you do that, you can control which file to load as follows...

```
java -jar -Dspring.datasource.platform=local application.jar
```

or

```
java -jar application.jar --spring.datasource.platform=remote
```

Comment: Is this best practice for pre load data?